# Is DeepAI.org a preprint server?

Tags: publications, computer-science, preprint, artificial-intelligence

I've noticed lots of new papers at [deepai.org](https://deepai.org/). I don't see very clear info. It seems you can submit a paper there, but it's not clear what this means in terms of copyright, etc...is it a preprint server? Has anyone posted a paper there and also published it in a journal?

Comment: Good question. It is definitely not _just_ a preprint server, at least. I have seen it automatically create profiles of authors and connect it with their twitter profiles, and list and link their papers on arXiv.

Answer (score 3):

**It does not seem to be a preprint server.** From spending a few minutes there, I do not see anywhere you can upload a paper. There are some featured papers, but they are all hosted on arXiv.

They don't have much of an about page, but they do say:

> The most popular research, guides, news and more in artificial intelligence

This sounds about right; their role seems to be *curating* existing content, such as articles, datasets, and even job ads, as well as some basic original content, like a glossary. They are a bit light on details about how this curation works.